# regression question

Tags: statistics, soft-question

Is the total sum of squares for multiple regression the same as the total sum of squares for anova?

Is anova a test for bivariate correlation or multiple regression?

Answer (score 0):

Anova typically takes symbolic variables (i.e. indicator for what experiment is formed) whereas linear regression takes all numeric variables and looks like a linear relationship. So while the concepts are related, they are not equivalent.